# Combine Print Ranges from Multiple Worksheets VBA EXCEL

Tags: vba, excel, printing

I am trying to figure out how to print the "ActiveSheet" or Sheet1 along with "Sheet5" (rows 1-6, A:M) being displayed at the bottom with a 2 row space in between the end of Sheet1 and the beginning of data from Sheet5.  I've been trying to look up similar questions and read something about a "Union" but I wasn't sure how it would fit here.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Sel_Manager As String
'Headers repeated at the top
Application.PrintCommunication = False
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = "$2:$2"
        .PrintTitleColumns = "$B:$M"
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = 1
End With

'Manager selection through ComboBox dropdown
 Sel_Manager = ComboBox1
'Inserting autofilters for worksheet
Cells.Select
Selection.AutoFilter
'Manager defined in the dropdown ComboBox
ActiveSheet.Range("B2", Range("M2").End(xlDown)).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Sel_Manager
ActiveSheet.Range("B2", Range("M2").End(xlDown)).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="A"
 'Here I select range to be printed and specify manager in filename
ActiveSheet.Range("B2", Range("M2").End(xlDown)).Select

Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
Sel_Manager + ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
Application.PrintCommunication = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `Set Rng3 = Union(Rng1, Rng2)` will create a combined range containing both Rng1 and Rng2.  Rng1 and Rng2 do not have to be contiguous but they do have to be within the same worksheet.  So `Union` would not help print bits of two worksheets.  You must create a new temporary worksheet and copy the required data from Sheet1 and Sheet5, print the temporary worksheet and then delete the temporary worksheet.

Comment: If I paste reference cells to Rng2 at the bottom of Rng1, is it possible to set Rng2 as a dynamic named range?  It needs to be dynamic because the user can add rows to Rng1 which would shift the Rng2 reference at the bottom down.  I tried using a named range but it locks the range at whichever rows you set it first and doesn't adjust when you insert rows.

Comment: I do not fully understand your question. How could the user add more rows while a macro is running?  A `Union` can combine up to 30 ranges: `Union(Rng1, Rng2, ... , Rng30)`.  `Union` is an intelligent function; If two ranges are contiguous, it will merge them. You can use `Union` on a range created with `Union`. `Set Rng1 = Union(Rng2, Rng3)` `Set Rng1 = Union(Rng1, Rng4)` is valid.

Comment: Sorry the file is rather complicated to explain.  It contains the wages for all employees and the history (6 years).  The owner wants it in this specific format so I have to work around it.   I have a userform where the HR manager can add employees.  So when adding employees to the data tab, she then can click on an "Add employee" button in the main tab that adds 4 rows to the bottom (showing the added employee).  I will try the union out and see if it works.  Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like a database... Access, SQL Server, etc, could do this with one form/subform combination, and certainly be more dependable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may give you some ideas.

I created two worksheets. One, called "Main", contains data that has "names" in column B and some As in column C. The other, called "Extra" contains the six rows to appear at the bottom of the filtered data.

I do not use Excel's identifiers when referencing worksheets. The first sheet will have an identifier of Sheet1 and a name of "Sheet1".  If you immediately create another sheet it will have an identifier of Sheet2 and a name of "Sheet2". However, if Sheet1 is renamed before the second sheet is created, it will have an identifier of Sheet2 and a name of "Sheet1". It can all get very confusing.

I have hardcoded the selected manager as "Aaaaa" rather than make it a user entered parameter. I have prepared worksheet "Main" for printing but have not output it.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

  Dim Manager As String
  Dim RngFiltered As Range
  Dim RowSht1Last As Long

  Manager = "Aaaaa"

  With Worksheets("Main")

    .AutoFilterMode = False   ' Switch off auto filtering if on

    ' Find last row containing a value
    RowSht1Last = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

    With .Range("B2:M2")
      .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Manager
      .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="A"
    End With

    Set RngFiltered = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    ' Just to show the filtered range.  Note, I cannot find a documented limit
    ' on the number of sub-ranges within a range. If there is a limit, I have
    ' never managed to reach it. However Range.Address has a limit which is a
    ' little under 255.
    Debug.Print Replace(RngFiltered.Address, "$", "")

    Worksheets("Extra").Range("A1:M6").Copy Destination:=.Cells(RowSht1Last + 2, "A")

    ' ###### Output visible rows

    ' Delete rows copied from Sheet5
    .Rows(RowSht1Last + 2 & ":" & RowSht1Last + 8).Delete

  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you!  I will give this a try.